# Creating 'Category list layout' in Umbraco which will show list of Textpages?

Tags: umbraco

As long-time Joomla administrator, I decided to try something new and I finally found Umbraco for which I believe is great CMS (specially for developers). I started creating my first website but I have some problems. In Joomla I used to use a lot of 'Category list layout' which is used to show articles in this order

http://docs.joomla.org/images/2/2a/Category_list_layout_example.png

And it always worked great and it most of the cases it suited for most of my clientd. I would like to achieve this in Umbraco. On my template I have this standard layout

[image]

Which is very simple. I would like to be able to make it look almost exactly like Joomla Category list layout but I don't know where to start? How can I add some additional columns beside Textpage title? How to make it visually like Joomla (one row - x color, second row - y color, third row - x color etc)?

Also are there any themes or similar which could be used only for this purpose? Perhaps some add-ons or similar?

Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance! 
MC

Comment: Are you talking about frontend or the administrations section?

Comment: Hello, I am talking about forntend part. Thanks in advance and best regards, MC

Comment: Ok perfect.  Then i have a lot of additional questions: Which version of Umbraco are you using?  Judging on the screenshot you installed an starter kit?  
do you know something of XSLT?  Have you already found out what razor is?  Have you looked at Umbraco TV?